# After update to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer I'm getting Token does not have a kid

Tags: jwt

I'm getting that message, after the update from 6 to 8.
IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid. Keys tried: '[PII of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '1'.
Number of keys in Configuration: '0'.
Exceptions caught:
'[PII of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
token: '[PII of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. See https://aka.ms/IDX10503 for details.

If I return to the version 6, it works again.

IssuerSigningKey =  new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("SecurityKey").Value))